# Runat="server" attribute not allowed in RTF fields

Tags: 2009

It seems tridion does not allow the runat="server" in tags within a RTF field.
This is how my tcmXHTML.config look like :

```
numeric-entities: true
drop-empty-paras: true
drop-proprietary-attributes: false
break-before-br: true
word-2000: false
wrap: 0
tidy-mark: false
uppercase-tags: false
uppercase-attributes: false
output-xml:true
logical-emphasis: true
fix-backslash: false
char-encoding: utf8
input-encoding: utf8
output-encoding: utf8
fix-uri: true
new-blocklevel-tags: video source
new-inline-tags: video source
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

There are some restrictions, even with the update of the configuration you indicate above (See [here for a similar question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11114/allowing-tags-in-the-rich-text-field)).

Whatever solution you add, it will likely require a '*technical*' element such as using a permitted format like `data-runat="server"` and then catching this pre-render and reformat as required) - but - **do** also consider the *author*.

Going into the source to add a specific 'technical looking' tag is not the optimum experience for editors - perhaps this could be achieved through some other technique such as encapsulating the required text in a specific format with some recognised notation...

> then the natural extension to this would be a GUI Extension to facilitate easier selection/formatting for your editors)

Re-iterating the [link above](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11114/allowing-tags-in-the-rich-text-field), you can see an example of the required code to replace from @johnwinter - additionally you could extend to include the runat="server" as a param such as default or explicitly required such as `{h:output runat="server"}tag content here {/h:output}`

Comment: I agree. Your code is supposed to go in your templates, not in your content - and the RTF is no exception to that.

Comment: I agree but unfortunately the website i'm working on right now is like this. We often have HTML blocks in RTF fields and that's a big problem not to be able to add this runat attribute

Comment: But "runat=server" isn't HTML, per se, right? Do the HTML blocks differ in each instance or are there certain selections of HTML and parameters that editors insert? If it's _anything_ or a good chunk of presented content, then a "code block" type Component might be a good fit. If the options are limited and inserted within RTF, then some type of placeholder text would be a good fit.

Comment: To add to Alvin's comments - we've seen the need for specific tags to be inserted around content (say to encapsulate some specific text for a controlled {web-side} section of clients) - for this we had linked RTF blocks - each with their own metadata to indicate the groups allowed to see (similarly you could have flags/selections to encapsulate the content with specific JAVA tags etc.) - difficult to envision without more clarity on the business, technical and editorial requirements

Answer (score 1):

Finally. I've decided to move the iframe HTML code to a template. Inside, the runat server was still not accepted but i could do something like this.

```
<script runat="server">
string runat = "runat=\"server\"";  
</script>

<iframe src="" <%= runat%></iframe>
```